# Razor syntax - escape so that text is not recognized as e-mail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically I want to display the version like "v1.1", where the version-number is in the ViewBag.

So I write v@ViewBag.Version in the markup.

But Razor will recognize this as an e-mail address.

I'm sure it will be blatantly obvious once I see it, but what is the escape to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  inside Razor, this way it will recognize your input as text.

```
<text>v</text>@ViewBag.Version
```

Comment: This works, but I was hoping for something more elegant, and re-sharper gives a warning: "Cannot resolve tag 'text'".

Comment: Have you tried the solution below with double '@'? It should work too

Comment: Why not add the 'v' to ViewBag.Version inside your controller to avoid all this hassle?

Comment: @@@ results in v@1.1, @@ results in v@ViewBag.Version

Comment: @adiga yes, that is a very good workaround, and there are others as well. I was just curious what the correct escape for it would be.

Comment: @Stokke you can try this: @Html.Raw("v")@ViewBag.Version

Answer (score 0):

Vsevolod Goloviznin has given the answer but I would add brackets '()', that is when you are in Razor (inside code `@{}` or `@if{}`, or `@foreach{}`), try to type this:

```
@:v@(ViewBag.Version)
```

`@:` is equivalent to `<text></text>` in Razer code, e.g.

```
@{
    <text>v</text>@(ViewBag.Version)
}
```

is the same as

```
@{
    @:v@(ViewBag.Version)
}
```